# Trying to pass <%> HTML Variable to Javascript - Node, Passport, and Stripe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

A bit of a newbie here. I've been looking for an answer that works and found some similarities in a Jade problem but I'm not using Jade. I have passed an "user" attribute into an HTML view as so:

```
app.get('/profile', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    res.render('profilePage/profilePage.html', {
        user : req.user // get the user out of session and pass to template
    });
});
```

Then, in my profile HTML, I can access my user property like so:

```
<%=user.local.firstname%>'s Profile
```

However, I want to allow Stripe to send the user's credit card info via the Stripetoken. I have managed to include a variable amount from a text field the user inputs. However, I want to append the user property so I can use it in my callback. Here is the javascript/jquery that's included in the profile html:

```
                      <!-- New section -->
                  <script type="text/javascript">
                    <!-- Fill in your publishable key -->
                    Stripe.setPublishableKey('pkkey');

                   var stripeResponseHandler = function(status, response) {
                     var $form = $('#contactForm');
                     var $amount = $('#amount').val();


                     if (response.error) {
                       // Show the errors on the form
                       $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
                       $form.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
                     } else {
                       // token contains id, last4, and card type
                       var token = response.id;

                       // Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
                       $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token));
                       $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="amount" />').val($amount));
                       // and re-submit
                       $form.get(0).submit();
                     }
                   };

                   jQuery(function($) {
                     $('#contactForm').submit(function(e) {
                       var $form = $(this);

                       // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
                       $form.find('button').prop('disabled', true);

                       Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);

                       // Prevent the form from submitting with the default action
                       return false;
                     });
                   });
                 </script>
```

As you can see, I have managed to append the $amount variable so I can access it in the callback:

```
module.exports = function(app, passport) {

app.post('/stripe', function(req,res) {
    // =====STRIPETOKEN======
    var transaction = req.body;
    var stripeToken = transaction.stripeToken;
    var donationAmount = transaction.amount;

    stripe.customers.create({
      source           : stripeToken,
      account_balance  : 0
    },function(err, customer) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log("Success!");
    }});
    // ====CREATE CHARGE======
    var charge =
        {
       amount    : donationAmount, 
       currency  : 'USD',
       card      : stripeToken
        };
        stripe.charges.create(charge, function(err, charge) {
           if(err)
            console.log(err);
            else
          {
                res.json(charge);
                console.log('Successful charge sent to Stripe!');
                console.log(charge);
          };
      });
    // ====PROFILE PAGE REDIRECT=====
    res.render('profilePage/profilePage.html', {
    });
});
```

So here's my problem. I want to pass the user's information, kind of like I did the amount, into the post method so when it redirects on success, I can pass it back in the res.render function, as well as send it to Stripe for description purposes. The only thing I can think of is to put the user info in a hidden field in HTML and access it like that, but that sounds messy and not proper.

This is my first time posting here so I apologize if it was too lengthy or not specific enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was in the way I was declaring passport and stripe in my application. Make sure you declare passport after everything to make the user variable available to stripe and all views.